# Will images be removed from within the local filesystem on update in iOS?

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store, appstore-approval

I am saving images captured from the camera within the local sandbox (filesystem) and store the filepath within my app to show the images (using Swift). I see that if I hit play in XCode, the images will be removed (which is ok)

Now I wonder what would happen if I submit this to the app store, the user saves images and I will update the app later on. Will the images will be removed as well?

To store the image, I use this function..

```
func saveImageLocally(imageData:NSData!) -> String{
        let time =  NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970
        let fileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
        let dir = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0].stringByAppendingPathComponent(subDirForImage) as String
        if !fileManager.fileExistsAtPath(dir) {
            var error: NSError?
            if !fileManager.createDirectoryAtPath(dir, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil, error: &error) {
                println("Unable to create directory: \(error)")
                return ""
            }
        }

        let path = dir.stringByAppendingPathComponent("IMAGENAME\(Int(time)).png")
        var error: NSError?
        if !imageData.writeToFile(path, options: NSDataWritingOptions.DataWritingAtomic, error: &error) {
            println("error writing file: \(error)")
            return ""
        }
        return path
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anything you store in your documents folder will persist through app updates providing you keep the same app ID and increment the version number.

Though it is worth noting that the full path to the app sandbox will be different (there will be a new sandbox for the update and the old data copied into it), so make sure you are only accessing resources by storing relative paths etc and are not storing full paths to images and expecting them to resolve after an update.

Comment: Hey, thanks, please have a look at my edited code. The function that returns the path is the one, I use. Is it save to use this path?

Comment: Yes, that should be fine. See https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010672-CH2-SW28  for all your options

Comment: great, thank you. EDIT. This is a OsX docu. This is also ok for iOs apps?

Comment: Yeah, it actually has sections for both OS (I linked you to the iOS section)